# Operaciones aritméticas en Base de Datos PostgreSQL

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, sql

Tengo una division que me opera dos enteros en una consulta, el problema es que el campo calculado me lo devuelve como un entero pero necesito me muestre los decimales tambien.

consulta:

```
select id_sibasi,id_semana_epidemiologica
sum(total_mosquitos),sum(total_anopheles)
(sum(total_mosquitos)/ sum(total_anopheles) )as indice from< pl_captura_anopheles
group by id_semana_epidemiologica,id_sibasi
```

La idea es sumar esos campos y dividirlos para mostrar un indice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select id_sibasi,id_semana_epidemiologica,
cast(sum(total_mosquitos)as numeric)as total,cast(sum(total_anopheles) as numeric) as anophles,
round(CAST(sum(total_mosquitos)as numeric) / CAST(sum(total_anopheles) AS numeric),4) as indice from
pl_captura_anopheles 
group by id_semana_epidemiologica,id_sibasi`

Answer (score 2):

Intenta de esta forma:

```
select id_sibasi,id_semana_epidemiologica,
sum(total_mosquitos),sum(total_anopheles),
CAST(sum(total_mosquitos)/ sum(total_anopheles), AS FLOAT) as indice from
pl_captura_anopheles 
group by id_semana_epidemiologica,id_sibasi
```

Comment: No, Lo siento simepre me los muestra entero

Comment: Intenta utilizar el mismo CAST con los campos individuales total_mosquitos y total_anopheles

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esto:

```
select id_sibasi,id_semana_epidemiologica,
sum(total_mosquitos)::numeric,sum(total_anopheles)::numeric,
(sum(total_mosquitos)::numeric/ sum(total_anopheles)::numeric)as indice from
pl_captura_anopheles 
group by id_semana_epidemiologica,id_sibasi
```

Answer (score 0):

No se exactamente como estan declarados tus campos pero te pondre un ejemplo como lo haria yo.

tengo una tabla digamos asi:

```
create table calculo(
numero1 int,
numero2 int 

)
```

y introdusco unos valores:

```
INSERT INTO calculo (numero1, numero2) VALUES (31,100);
```

para hacer una cunsulta y que me devuelva el numero con sus decimales lo pongo de esta manera:

```
   select numero1,numero2, numero2/CONVERT(decimal(4,2), numero1) as indicecalculado from
    calculo;
```

de esta manera el campo calculado me devuelve valores con sus respectivos decimales, acomodalo a tu consulta ahora.

Comment: No ,esa me da error al ejecutar tu codigo descrito

Comment: Pues a mi me funciona PERFECTAMENTE.

Answer (score 0):

Realiza la operación y convierte su resultado a double precision

> ( campo1 / campo2 ) :: double precision
>
> *vigila que no haya nulos con una función coalesce o que estés dividiendo con 
>     ceros.